# Distributed Rendering in the UDK and Unity

Tags: unity, rendering, udk, distribution

At the moment I'm looking at getting a game engine to run in a [CAVE environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_automatic_virtual_environment). So far, during my research I've seen a lot of people being able to get both Unity and the Unreal engine up and running in a CAVE (someone did get CryEngine to work in one, but there is little research data about it).

As of yet, I have not cemented my final choice of engine for use in the next stage of my project. I've experience in both, so the learning curve will be gentle on both. And both of the engines offer stereoscopic rendering, either already inbuilt with ReadD (Unreal) or by doing it yourself (Unity). Both can also make use of other input devices as well, such as the kinect or other devices. So again, both engines are still on the table.

For the last bit of my preliminary research, I was advised to see if either, or both engines could do distributed rendering.

I was advised this, as the final game we make could go into a variety of differently sized CAVEs. The one I have access to is roughly 2.4m x 3m cubed, and have been duly informed that this one is a "baby" compared to others.

So, finally onto my question:

- Can either the Unreal Engine, or Unity Engine make it possible for developers to allow distributed rendering? Either through in built devices, or by creating my own plugin / script?

Comment: Do you mean distributed across several computers? If yes I'm afraid that the answer is simply "no, neither can". At least not out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have several computers rendering different views for your CAVE, (which I think is what you are suggesting), I think you would have to effectively create a networked game, with the controls on one node being sent and replicated on all the others.

You will have to expend some effort ensuring that all the nodes stay synchronised; I would suggest using a [lock-step networking](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php) approach; this means that you have to ensure that the simulation on all machines is completely deterministic, but makes the networking fairly straightforward as you only have to send the user input across the network to each node.